# Copy the result of a filter function in a cell from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Sheet named "A" and in one Cell (J1) I apply a filter:

**J1:** `=filter(A:F,C:C="Seen")`

and it results in many rows.

Then I have another Sheet named "B" and I want to copy all these columns and rows (the result of the filter) in a Cell in "B" (G1)

**G1:** `=A!J1`

However, when I do this I don't copy all the rows and columns (the result of the filter apply in cell J1 of Sheet "A") I just get the value of J1 in "A".

How Can I copy ALL the result of the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

- paste in **G1** cell on sheet B: `=FILTER(A!A:F, A!C:C="Seen")`
- paste in **G1** cell on sheet B: `=A!J1:O`